# Cannot change a value in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Is python changing this much?
I tried to google, but seems python is changing everyday, and I have tried many ways.
for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['LOGIN', 'Tag', 'Tag Date'])
df.loc[0] = (2222,'na','2020-09-21')
```

```
df_RV[df_RV['LOGIN']==2222]['Tag']
0    na
Name: Tag, dtype: object
```

Change the value:

```
df_RV[df_RV['LOGIN']==2222]['Tag'] = 'Are you ok'
```

But it is not changed...

```
df_RV[df_RV['LOGIN']==201043]['Tag']
0    na
Name: Tag, dtype: object
```

Because it is a view or copy problem, thus the value has been changed in the view but not on the df.
Many solutions are many years old.
I have tried the way like to use .loc, but still; what is the current best way to change a value?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is being assigned to a copy of the dataframe and not to the original one. This format works.

```
df.loc[df['LOGIN'] == 2222, ['Tag']] = 'Are you ok'
```